# For what class of functions is the following integral finite?

Tags: definite-integrals, continuity, regularity-theory-of-pdes

For $f\colon [-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ consider 
$$
\int_{-1}^1 (f(x) - f(-1))^2 \frac{1}{1+x}\, \mathrm{d}x.
$$

How nice (how continuous, how regular, how ...) does $f$ have to be for this integral to be finite?  Put another way, what is a broad class of functions for which this integral is finite?

As a follow up, does there exist a constant $C>0$ such that for all $f$ such that the integral is finite\ we have

$$\int_{-1}^1 (f(x)-f(-1))^2 \frac{1}{1+x}\, \mathrm{d} x \le C( |f(-1)| + \left\| f \right\|_{L^2})?$$

Thanks

Comment: Hoelder continuous at $x=-1$ and integrable on $[-1,1]$ should suffice.

Comment: @Dr.MV I am writing to let you know that I have added a follow up question.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dr.MV I would say $f$ is Holder-$\alpha$ continuous at $-1, \alpha > 1/2,  \,f\in L^2$ would suffice.

Comment: @zhw Yes; missed the square.

Comment: I now see that $\alpha > 1/2$ is not needed. Any $\alpha > 0$ is enough. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: Here's the sufficient condition that @Dr.MV and I were discussing in the comments: Suppose $p>0,-1<b\le 1.$ Suppose $f$ satisfies

i) $|f(x)-f(-1)|\le C|x+1|^p$ in $[-1,b];$

ii) $f\in L^2[-1,1].$

Then the given integral is finite. Proof: i) shows the full integrand is $\le C^2(x+1)^{2p-1}$ on $[-1,b],$ which gives integrability over $[-1,b].$ ii) shows the rest of the integral is finite. (Note $f\in L^2[-1,1]$ implies $f\in L^1[-1,1].$ So when you expand the square to get $f(x)^2 -2f(x)f(-1) + f(-1)^2$ upstairs, the full integrand is integrable over $[-1,b].$)

This shows for example that any $f\in L^2[-1,1]$ that is differentiable at $-1$ yields a finite integral.

Follow-up question: The answer is no. Consider $f_n(x) =(1+x)^{1/n}$ to see this.